# How to grab objects methods when iterating through ArrayList?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I am trying to figure out how to use an object's methods when iterating through an ArrayList. However, there is a part of the question that I couldn't fit above, and it's that in the ArrayList, there are objects, lets call them Shoes, that inherit from, lets say Clothes. But there are also Shirts and Socks in this array, that also each inherit from Clothes. So the array is of type Clothes, in order to accommodate the different types of objects in it. Observe:

```
ArrayList<Clothes> list = new ArrayList<Clothes>();
list.add(shoe);
list.add(shirt);
list.add(sock);
```

And this works because they all inherit from Clothes. However, I am trying to iterate through this ArrayList and use each object's unique methods like so:

```
for(Clothes piece : list) {
...//something like piece.getShoeSize();
}
```

Say I wanted to print out the shoes' sizes when a button is pressed, or the colors of each of the socks when a different button is pressed. I am unable to do this because, in the for loop itself, it is only looking for things that are of type Clothes, but when I change Clothes to Shoes, it doesn't work either, because list is a list of type Clothes. I've tried casting *piece* as a shoe or shirt, depending on the result of the if-statement

```
if(piece instanceof Shoe) {
...//((Shoe) piece).getShoeSize();
}
```

But that doesn't work either. If you have any ideas, I would greatly appreciate the help.

EDIT: For clarity.

Here is the class hierarchy:

```
public class Clothes {
getColor();
}

public class Sock extends Clothes {
...
}

public class Shirt extends Clothes {
getSize();
}

public class Shoe extends Clothes {
getSize();
}
```

So my program has a JComboBox with various things inside it. It also has a JTextArea beneath it. What I am trying to get my program to do is print out something into the JTextArea depending on what option is selected in the JComboBox. So let's say there is an option SIZE in the JComboBox. When it is selected, I want all of the objects that are in `list`, that are also capable of performing the method `getSize()`, to perform the method `getSize()`, which prints out the size of the object (like XL or 10.5) to the JTextArea. Now, because the class Clothes does not have a `getSize()` method (because not all clothes have definitive sizes. For example, Socks), I am having issues. The `list` is of type Clothes, so in the for-loop, I must declare the type of object as Clothes. But the `piece` is therefore also of type Clothes, so when I try to run `getSize()` on it, it gives me an error, because Clothes does not have a method `getSize()` in it. However, some of the objects in `list` do have this method. So my question is how to access this method for objects in the ArrayList `list` which is of type Clothes.

Comment: Why do you check for instance of `shoe`, but cast to `Shoe`. Is this typo?

Comment: @KenBekov No it's not a typo. I'm checking to see if the object in list is of type Shoe, but then I must cast it to Shoe because 'piece' is of type Clothes, because of the for-loop

Comment: I mean, in your code snippet you use `shoe` starting with lower case, and `Shoe` starting with upper case. Different things. When you say 'doesn't work', what do you mean? Have you any exceptions?

Comment: Should this: `piece instanceof shoe` not be `piece instanceof Shoe`

Comment: What error message are you getting when casting to Shoe?

Comment: @KenBekov ah yes, that was a typo. Fixed it. I mean it gives me an error when I try to run it.

Comment: @Bob The method that I am trying to access is in both Shoe and Sock, but not in Clothes, so when I cast to Shoe, it gives me the error that Sock cannot be cast to Shoe.

Comment: Seems like you `Shoe` inherited from `Sock`. Is it so?

Comment: @KenBekov No that is not the case. Sock and Shoe are different classes. But lets say I had a method getSize() that Shoe and Shirt had in common. Using the for-each-loop above, I would try to call that method for the objects that have that method, but it won't allow me.

Comment: If this classes are different, then `Sock` never pass checking for `instance of Shoe`, and you would never get error that `Sock cannot be cast to Shoe`. Something unclear in you description. It will be more clear, if you would apply class hierarchy.

Comment: @KenBekov I edited the post with class hierarchy and a better description of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You could try getClass.getDeclaredMethods()

Comment: @Bob what does that return and how would I access just the method that I am looking for?

Comment: Actually, in you case check for `instance of` must to work. You have properly designed hierarchy of classes. I have no idea, why you got exception.

Comment: @Bob the documentation says it is of type Array, but that the methods are not sorted in any order. how do I perform only the method that I am looking for?

Comment: @KenBekov I am getting an exception because I am calling a method on `piece` that the class Clothes, of which `piece` is a member, does not have. It is something that another class, which inherits from Clothes, has.

Comment: Find the method in the array named getSize and save it in a var. Then var.invoke(piece, null). This is reflection in case you want to look at the java tutorial. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-reflection-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The only thing I had to do was call

```
new Main();
```

inside of

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

and put all of my code inside of Main(), and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use inheritance to do this quite nicely!

```
public abstract class Clothes {

    public abstract void printTo(JTextArea out);
}

public class Shoes {

    private int size;

    public Shoes(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void printTo(JTextArea out) {
        out.println("Shoe size is: " + size);
    }
}

public class Socks {

    private String color;

    public Shoes(String colr) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void printTo(JTextArea out) {
        out.append("Socks color is: " + color);
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it simply like:

```
JTextArea myArea = new JTextArea();

list.add(new Shoes(12));
list.add(new Socks("red with a dash of blue"));

for (Clothes piece : list) {
    piece.printTo(myArea);
}
```

And get something like:

```
Shoes size is: 12
Socks color is: red with a dash of blue
```

---

Here, `Clothes` has an [`abstract` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) named `printTo` that allows subclasses of `Clothes`, such as `Shoes` and `Socks`, to define how they want to print.

So in this case, `Shoes` will override `printTo` and print out the corresponding shoe size. This is defined by `Shoes` and allows direct access to all the information, such as `size`.

`Socks` defines `printTo` to print out the corresponding color. Once again, this is up to `Socks` to define what and how it is printed.

Now in the loop, it doesn't matter if the `Clothes` object is `Shoes` or `Socks`, they both inherit the `printTo` method from `Clothes`. This method is then invoking, leaving it up to the implementations of `Clothes` to determine what and how to print.

---

[Java Inheritance - Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: The problem is that the method that I'm trying to access is not in the Clothes class, it is unique to the Shoes class.

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 Yes, and unless you are doing casting and `instanceof` checks (which has quite a bad code smell), abstraction like this is the way to go.

Comment: the method that I'm trying to access is something that the Shoe object did not inherit from Clothes.

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 do you intend to use the data within the for-loop? If so, this is still do-able but would require more work. This might also be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are asking how to fix your attempted solution instead of solving the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the data in the for-loop. I want the individual objects that are in the list to perform a certain method that is specific to them. But because they are of different types, I cannot do it as far as I can see, which is not far at all (I'm still somewhat of a beginner). I'm not asking to fix my solution, because my solution doesn't work at all.

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 I feel like you've left out quite a bit of information, including what you actually intend to do with this (thus the XY). And as for what you say you want it to do - perform a certain method that is specific to them - something like I posted would do just that. And I'm 100% sure you can do it, you just need to be clearer with what you actually intend to do.

Comment: I could edit the question to be more clear, it is just a really complicated scenario. I will do it now.

Comment: I see your edit, and I could go back to the Clothes class and add all the methods that I would need to access from the other classes, like getSize(). I am just wondering if there is a way to do this without doing that. (Also, I don't know why the comments aren't showing me saying @Obicere at the beginning.)

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 as you can see with this example, you wouldn't need to do that. You would just need the single method (`printTo` in this case). Then, when you define it in `Shoes`, that method has full access to all the information in the `Shoes` class. And if you have a `Shirt` class, it would have all the information available in the `Shirt` class.

Comment: so what you are saying is that, in order to access the methods that I desire, I must define them in the Clothes, so anything that inherits from Clothes has those methods? What if I create a class that inherits from clothes that doesn't need that method? @Obicere

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 No. Methods pertaining to a shoe belong in the `Shoes` class, not the `Clothes` class. Only define methods in `Clothes` that every `Clothes` object needs to have. In the example code, every subclass needs to define how to print to a `JTextArea` through the `printTo` method. Then, each class defines how it does it, specific to that class.

Comment: that seems like it would work. Is it the only way to do this? @Obicere

Comment: @ipodfreak0313 No, there are other ways, but this is the simplest and safest. It is a fairly common practice in Java.